# Only run gitlab pipeline job if any committed file is not one of three specific types

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab (v16.6.2-ee) pipeline job and i want it to only run, when I'm on a feature branch and when one of the committed files does not have the type `*.abc`, `*.def` or `*.xyz`.

Using this does not work

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - "**/*[^.abc]"
    - "**/*[^.def]"
    - "**/*[^.xyz]"
```

because it evaluates to true, as soon as one of the bullet points matches.

Also this gives an invalid yaml:

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - "**/*[^.abc]" && "**/*[^.def]" && "**/*[^.xyz]"
```

And here the second changes seems to override the first

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - "**/*[^.abc]"
  changes:
    - "**/*[^.def]"
```

And the regex (which works fine in a regex tester) does not trigger the correct pipelines either (I read that [negative lookaheads](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#only--except-regex-syntaxhttps://) are not supported):

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  changes:
    - /^(.(?!.*\.abc$|.*\.def$|.*\.xyz$))*$/
```

I'm out of ideas. And because there is a vast variety of other file types the job should run for, I'd like to refrain from the positive version, where the job runs, if a file type matches this or that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first problem you're running into is that `rules:changes:` are **glob patterns**, not regex patterns. Specifically, as mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), these must be expressions supported by Ruby's [`fnmatch`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/File.html#method-c-fnmatch). So, you must write a glob pattern for this.

Because `rules:changes:` is an inclusive set, in order to *exclude* patterns, you need to write a glob pattern that is inclusive of every possible file that does *not* end in the extensions you're describing. Normally, the `!` metacharacter could be used for this generally, but GitLab does not support this metacharacter, unfortunately.

However, you can write an exhaustive pattern that covers, roughly*, the same cases.

```
rules:
  changes:
    - "**/*.{[^adx]*,a[^b]*,ab[^c]*,abc?*,a,ab,d[^e]*,de[^f]*,def?*,d,de,x[^y]*,xy[^z]*,xyz?*,x,xy,}"
```

See [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%2A%2F%2A.%7B%5B%5Eadx%5D%2A%2Ca%5B%5Eb%5D%2A%2Cab%5B%5Ec%5D%2A%2Cabc%3F%2A%2Ca%2Cab%2Cd%5B%5Ee%5D%2A%2Cde%5B%5Ef%5D%2A%2Cdef%3F%2A%2Cd%2Cde%2Cx%5B%5Ey%5D%2A%2Cxy%5B%5Ez%5D%2A%2Cxyz%3F%2A%2Cx%2Cxy%2C%7D&matches=false&options=dot%3Atrue&tests=%2F%2F%20these%20should%20NOT%20match%20the%20pattern&tests=file.abc&tests=file.def&tests=file.xyz&tests=foobar%2Ffile.abc&tests=foobar%2Ffile.def&tests=foobar%2Ffile.xyz&tests=%2F%2F%20these%20SHOULD%20match&tests=%2F%2F%20files%20with%20different%20extensions&tests=readme.md&tests=.gitlab-ci.yml&tests=%2F%2F%20extensionless%20files%20with%20leading%20underscores&tests=.gitignore&tests=%2F%2F%20files%20with%20extensions%20that%20are%20supersets%20of%20the%20extensions&tests=file.abcd&tests=file.xyzextra&tests=%2F%2F%20substrings%20of%20the%20extensions&tests=file.a&tests=file.ab&tests=file.xy&tests=%2F%2F%20notably%2C%20however%2C%20files%20without%20extensions%20are%20NOT%20covered%20by%20this%20pattern&tests=noext&tests=dir%2Fnoext&tests=CHANGELOG&tests=%2F%2F%20Files%20with%20multiple%20%22.%22%20characters%20does%20not%20work%20as%20desired&tests=%2F%2F%20This%20matches%20but%2C%20ideally%2C%20should%20not.&tests=foo.foo.abc) for tests of this glob pattern.

Breaking it down, this pattern contains rules that matches files that have an extension:

- that doesn't start with `a`, `d` or `x` (`[^adx]*`)
- that starts with `a`, but doesn't contain `b` as its second character (`a[^b]*`)
- that starts with `ab`, but doesn't contain `c` as its third character (`ab[^c]*`)
- that starts with `abc` but has at least one additional character (`abc?*`)
- that is just `a` or just `ab` (`.a,.ab`)
- (and repeat the preceding 4 rules for each set of extension characters)

---

* Notably, however, this won't cover extensionless files like `LICENSE` or similar. You may have to add any extensionless files you have manually as additional array items to `rules:changes:`. It also will match files with multiple `.` characters, even if it ends in `abc`/`def`/`xyz` like `foo.foo.abc`.

There's likely a way to write a pattern that doesn't have these caveats, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Oh, crazy. I had no clue how the glob syntax works and now I see so many errors in my original question. Thank you. Your suggestion works as described. I'll have to think about how relevant the caveats are.

Comment: What does the `,` at the end just before the `}` do?

Comment: @numberfourteen Nothing :)

Comment: But when I play around with the glob-tool you posted above, I get different results, depending on whether I add a comma at the end or not. This `**/*{.[^m]*,.m[^d]*,.md?*,.m}` results in `test.md` not being matched, which I expect, but adding a comma like `**/*{.[^m]*,.m[^d]*,.md?*,.m,}` matches `test.md`.